# Window cannot be resized after change the look and feel

Tags: java, swing

I changed look and feel of a swing application after the start on a button click event. But after changing the look and feel in a smaal window then its window size cannot be resized. If we change the look and feel in a maximized window it works perfectly.

Here is my code

```java
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new AluminiumLookAndFeel());
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(nextFrame);
nextFrame.pack();
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
this.pack();
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner

Comment: @Amith there are a few version, which one

Comment: 'AluminiumLookAndFeel' - for a non-standard L&F, try their forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting basic(JAVA) look and feel for the first time program launches and then changed to external by using a combo box.

Comment: I believe the cause of this is related the the particular LookAndFeel.  I don't know the specifics, but the the LookAndFeel being used seems to render the minimize, maximize, and close buttons differently than others and makes the normal buttons invisible.  When the theme switches, it doesn't make the buttons visible again.